# Identify similar entries based on two criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I'm trying identify different status of a product for same colour by using the below formula

=IF(B6&J6=B5&J5,IF(OR(B6&J6&L6=B5&J5&L5,B6&J6&L6=B7&J7&L7),"True","False"),"True")

**Result**

[image]

**Expected Result**

[image]

However, unable to achieve the expected result. I completely lost here kindly lend me a hand :)

Comment: Your formula gives TRUE if the status matches the previous or next status for the same product & colour, which is why the last two lines of your results are both TRUE. Maybe you want to see if the status is different from the usual or most common status for the product & colour? I think the question needs making a bit more precise.

Comment: Please suggest me one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible answer. Count how many times the most common status (Seasonal) occurs for the current product and colour, then count how many times the status in the current row occurs. If the counts are the same, then this is the most common status so set the result to TRUE, otherwise FALSE.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$20,A2,$B$2:$B$20,B2,$C$2:$C$20,C2)=MAX(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$20,A2,$B$2:$B$20,B2,$C$2:$C$20,$C$2:$C$20))
```

Must be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

or you can try

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$20,A2,$B$2:$B$20,B2,$C$2:$C$20,C2)=AGGREGATE(14,0,COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$20,A2,$B$2:$B$20,B2,$C$2:$C$20,$C$2:$C$20),1)
```

entered as a normal formula.

Here is a screen shot using your specified columns

[image]

Comment: That's great. Will add non-array alternative.

Comment: both formulas are working nicely Thanks again :)
I'm wondering this formula is working in one sheet and in another sheet its not working!! Any settings i need to update?

Comment: Also if I'm changing range A - B, B-J, C-L it doesn't work :(

Comment: I don't know why that is - no setting that I can think of. Will add screenshot with cols B/J/L.